# Programmatically access windows share in php via kerberos or ntlm

Tags: php, iis-7.5, kerberos, ntlm, samba

I have a few requirements here on which I am not sure if they're even possible the way they're requested. Sorry beforehand for not having code, but I feel stackoverflow fits the most for this question, and I can't write code on company time before the situation is clear.

**Setup**
A windows server with an IIS and PHP running via FCGI. There's an intranet (php/mysql) running on this machine. Users currently have anonymous access to it, since it is an open intranet. All users are in the same windows domain.

**SSO and windows shares**
As far as my research got, single sign on via NTLM is possible and should not be a biggie to implement into the current intranet. However, there's a plugin running which reads directories  from defined windows shares, and spits out a file list. Those files are read by a specific user account having read access to this share.

Is it possible to authenticate the current user at the windows share to read files, via that data I receive from SSO (via ntlm or kerberos or ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Kerberos, Credential Deleagtion and Impersonation. Forget NTLM.

Edit: On Windows, this is solved by SSPI, on Unix by GSS-API.

Comment: Thanks for those keywords!